# Facebook Like button picture missing

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to understand why my image does not show up when a user hits the like button on my site.  The debugger show the correct image but it will not display it in Facebook when you like the page.  Here is the URL.

http://www.pausethis.com/Home/Video?video=http://www.youtube.com/embed/-cZ7OT7BmM8?wmode=opaque&id=95&VId=-cZ7OT7BmM8

Any ideas?

Facebook-like

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this. The image does appear when you like the link. However, the title (i.e. `og:title`) of the page is incorrect. It prints a URL instead of the actual title or something useful.

[image: Like Screenshot]

Comment: That is strange.  I just did it again and the graphics still does not show up on my facebook page.  I do not understand that.